# using multiple <router-outlet> in angular 7

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular7

I am trying to configure my routes as below:

**'' => layout page**
**'home => home'** this has another router-outlet to switch views
**'details/:id'** child of /home, will be rendered by second router-outlet

**My routing-module.ts**

```
    [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent,
      children: [

        {
          path: 'home/details/:id',
          component: ContactDetailsComponent,
          outlet: 'out2'
        },
       }
     ];
```

**Parent-component.html**

```
    <some-tags></some-tags>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Home-component.html**

```
 <main class="d-flex">
  <app-contact-list></app-contact-list>
  <router-outlet name="out2"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

What I am missing here?, thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Figured it out**

As I have all components in a single module i.e all my components are siblings of each other, So I don't need to add another named `<router-outlet>` this can be done by a single `<router-outlet>`.

*previous routes worked, when I removed outlet from the routes and used lazy loaded routes.*

**Revised routes**

```
   const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [
      { path: ':id/details', component: Component2 },
      { path: ':id/update', component: Component3 },
      { path: 'add', component: Component4 },
    ] },
];
```